# Why are there little white dots on my bw negative, and how can I fix it?

Tags: black-and-white, developing, negative-film, negative

I've been deving some bw film at home, but on one of my negatives there are a lot of little white spots everywhere.

Why has this happened, how can I prevent it from happening again, and how can I fix it?

My scanner does not have a clean option, so it's probably fix one by one in photoshop.

Thank you! Any advice is much appreciated.

[image: example]

Comment: Looks like dust. How clean is your dev environment from the change bag through to the drying rack? Specifically with drying, is it done in a clean place with no airflow or only cleaned airflow?

Comment: there could be a slight airflow. they dry next to a window which could have been left open for this set of negatives

Comment: Windows are always drafty. If you have no dedicated place, then try using a seldom used closet and, once hung up, make sure not to open the door for ~a day. Make sure any AC/Heating vents in the room are also closed. No airflow is better than non-filtered air.

Answer (score 2):

It's been many years since I've done film developing, but I remember two likely culprits:

1. Air bubbles from improper agitation. Generally these are very round*ish*.
2. Minerals from hard water. These tend to be angular shapes.

Comment: could be improper agitation or drying, as I believe the water in my area is soft

Answer (score 1):

Since [you note](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100849/75526#comment188019_100849):

> they dry next to a window which could have been left open for this set of negatives

As Hueco explains ([1](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100849/75526#comment187959_100849), [2](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/100849/75526#comment188022_100849)):

> Looks like dust. How clean is your dev environment from the change bag through to the drying rack? Specifically with drying, is it done in a clean place with no airflow or only cleaned airflow?
>
> Windows are always drafty. If you have no dedicated place, then try using a seldom used closet and, once hung up, make sure not to open the door for ~a day. Make sure any AC/Heating vents in the room are also closed. No airflow is better than non-filtered air.